# Multiple Choices error inviting a user through the Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've had a working process inviting external users through the Microsoft Graph. The is the documentation: [Invitation manager](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation) & [Create invitation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post)

It has run successfully for a while and now it broke with the error:

```
StatusCode: 300 - Ambigious

ReasonPhrase: Multiple Choices
```

I have no clue on what this error means. I've checked if there's already a user in AAD, but that's not the case. And I can't find anything relevant through Google.

Update: it seems to be specific to one user. I've changed my code and other users seem to work fine. Still no clue on why it wouldn't work for this user.

Update 2: The user has already been invited and has accepted the invitation. Now he is re-invited using an alias in (what I assume) the same Office 365 source tenant. Maybe that's an explanation for this error.

Update 3: I used my dev tenant as the 'external' tenant, and invited myself on both the main UPN as on an alias. This is not causing the same issue, and doesn't seem to be an explanation.

Comment: That's a strange error, checking docs, they have documentation only for 400+

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `invitedUserDisplayName`to rename a new, which is different from the previous invited, and then invited again.

Comment: I already set that value. And the display name is different than the one already in the tenant. I've tested various alterations.